# Colored table cell with multirow lets text disappear behind next colored cell

Tags: tables, color, multirow

I stumbled over something I do not know how to solve.
I don't even know about layers in LaTeX but it seems like my text is disappearing behind a colored cell beneath it and that because I use a multirow.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[
10pt,
a4paper,
]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[
  svgnames,
  table,
  ]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\up}[2]{\rotatebox[origin=#1]{90}{#2}}
\begin{longtable}{|>{\columncolor{LightSlateGray!10!white}}
                   c % Phase
                  |p{0.02\paperwidth} % PSP-Code
                  |p{0.15\paperwidth} % AP
                  |p{0.03\paperwidth} % AP-V.
                  |p{0.05\paperwidth} % Datum
                  |p{0.18\paperwidth} % Prüfmeth.
                  |p{0.03\paperwidth} % Prüfer
                 |} \rowcolor{LightSlateGray!10!white}
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{Phase} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{\up{l}{PSP-Code}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{\up{l}{Arbeitspaket (AP)}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{\up{l}{AP-Verantwortlich}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{\up{l}{Datum (bis)}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{Prüfmethode} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{\up{l}{Prüfungs Verantwortlich.}}\\ \hline \endhead
  \multirow{2}{*}{Projektpläne} &
    1.1 & Dokumentation & PL & 20.11.18 &
    Mündlicher Review & FAM \\\cline{2-7} &
    1.2 & Projekt-Umweltanalyse & PL & 25.11.18 &
    Walk Through & SE \\\hline
  \multirow{3}{*}{Grobplanung} &
    2.1 & Evaluation Node & PL & 04.12.18 &
    Mündlicher Review & DB \\\cline{2-7} &
    2.2 & Evaluation Host & PL & 08.12.18 &
    Mündlicher Review  & DB \\\cline{2-7} &
    2.3 & Gewichtung der Evaluation & PL & 08.01.19 &
    Mündlicher Review & DB \\\hline
  \multirow{3}{*}{Material} &
    3.1 & BOM & PL & 12.01.19 &
    Walk-Through & PL \\\cline{2-7} &
    3.2 & Bestellung & PL & 16.01.19 &
    Walk-Through & PL \\\cline{2-7} &
    3.3 & Assemblierung & PL & 28.02.19 &
    Funktionstest & PL \\\hline
  \multirow{2}{*}{Software} &
    4.1 & Node & PL & 05.03.19 &
    Funktionstest & PL \\\cline{2-7} &
    4.2 & Host & PL & 10.03.19 &
    Funktionstest & PL \\\cline{2-7}
  \multirow{3}{*}{Tests} &
    5.1 & Node Tests & PL & 12.01.19 &
    Schriftlicher Review & PL \\\cline{2-7} &
    5.2 & Host Tests & PL & 16.01.19 &
    Schriftlicher Review & PL \\\cline{2-7} &
    5.3 & Systemtests & PL & 28.02.19 &
    Schriftlicher Review & PL \\\hline
  \caption{Prüfplan}
  \label{tab:pruefplan}
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image: pruefplan]

Comment: does nobody have a clue how this happens?

Answer (score 2):

in your case the `multirow` cells had to be in the last row and have negative number of spanning rows:

```
\documentclass[
10pt,
a4paper
]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[
  svgnames,
  table,
  ]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\up}[2]{\rotatebox[origin=#1]{90}{#2}}
\begin{longtable}{|>{\columncolor{LightSlateGray!10!white}}
                   c % Phase
                  |p{0.02\paperwidth} % PSP-Code
                  |p{0.15\paperwidth} % AP
                  |p{0.03\paperwidth} % AP-V.
                  |p{0.05\paperwidth} % Datum
                  |p{0.18\paperwidth} % Prüfmeth.
                  |p{0.03\paperwidth} % Prüfer
                 |} \rowcolor{LightSlateGray!10!white}
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{Phase} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{\up{l}{PSP-Code}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{\up{l}{Arbeitspaket (AP)}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{\up{l}{AP-Verantwortlich}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{\up{l}{Datum (bis)}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{Prüfmethode} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{\up{l}{Prüfungs Verantwortlich.}}\\ \hline \endhead
%
    & 1.1 & Dokumentation & PL & 20.11.18 & Mündlicher Review & FAM \\
    \cline{2-7}
\multirow{-2}{*}{Projektpläne}
    & 1.2 & Projekt-Umweltanalyse & PL & 25.11.18 & Walk Through & SE \\\hline
%
   & 2.1 & Evaluation Node & PL & 04.12.18 & Mündlicher Review & DB \\\cline{2-7}
    & 2.2 & Evaluation Host & PL & 08.12.18 & Mündlicher Review & DB \\\cline{2-7}
\multirow{-3}{*}{Grobplanung}
    & 2.3 & Gewichtung der Evaluation & PL & 08.01.19 & Mündlicher Review & DB \\\hline
%
    & 3.1 & BOM & PL & 12.01.19 & Walk-Through & PL \\\cline{2-7}
    & 3.2 & Bestellung & PL & 16.01.19 & Walk-Through & PL \\\cline{2-7}
\multirow{-3}{*}{Material}
    & 3.3 & Assemblierung & PL & 28.02.19 & Funktionstest & PL \\\hline
%
    & 4.1 & Node & PL & 05.03.19 & Funktionstest & PL \\\cline{2-7}
 \multirow{-2}{*}{Software}
    & 4.2 & Host & PL & 10.03.19 & Funktionstest & PL \\
    \hline
%
    & 5.1 & Node Tests & PL & 12.01.19 & Schriftlicher Review & PL \\ \cline{2-7}
    & 5.2 & Host Tests & PL & 16.01.19 & Schriftlicher Review & PL \\ \cline{2-7}
\multirow{-3}{*}{Tests}
    & 5.3 & Systemtests & PL & 28.02.19 & Schriftlicher Review & PL \\
    \hline
  \caption{Prüfplan}
  \label{tab:pruefplan}
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

i wonder, do you really need `longtable` (is real table multi page long?) and have colored first column and row?

from your code i suspect, that the ordinary `tabular` in `table` float would be better. after redefining column width (now table is out of text area), the table can be designed as follows:

```
\documentclass[
a4paper
]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{longtable,
            makecell,   % <--new
            multirow}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}

\usepackage[
  svgnames,
  table,
  ]{xcolor}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
\caption{Prüfplan}
\label{tab:pruefplan}
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\settowidth\rotheadsize{AP-Verantwortlich}
\begin{tabular}{|  p{0.12\linewidth} % Phase
                  |c % PSP-Code
                  |>{\raggedright}p{0.21\linewidth} % AP
                  |l % AP-V.
                  |l % Datum
                  |l % Prüfmeth.
                  |l % Prüfer
                 |} 
    \hline
\rothead{Phase}
        & \rothead{PSP-Code}            & \rothead{Arbeitspaket\\ (AP)}
        & \rothead{AP-Verantwortlich}   & \rothead{Datum\\ (bis)}
        & \rothead{Prüfmethode}         & \rothead{Prüfungs\\ Verantwortlich.} \\ \hline 
%
\multirow{3}{=}{Projekt\-pläne}
    & 1.1 & Dokumentation & PL & 20.11.18 & Mündlicher Review & FAM \\
    \cline{2-7}
    & 1.2 & Projekt-Umweltanalyse & PL & 25.11.18 & Walk Through & SE \\\hline
%
\multirow{5}{=}{Grob\-planung}
   & 2.1 & Evaluation Node & PL & 04.12.18 & Mündlicher Review & DB \\\cline{2-7}
    & 2.2 & Evaluation Host & PL & 08.12.18 & Mündlicher Review & DB \\\cline{2-7}
\multirow{3}{=}{Material}
    & 2.3 & Gewichtung der Evaluation & PL & 08.01.19 & Mündlicher Review & DB \\\hline
%
\multirow{3}{=}{Material}
    & 3.1 & BOM & PL & 12.01.19 & Walk-Through & PL \\\cline{2-7}
    & 3.2 & Bestellung & PL & 16.01.19 & Walk-Through & PL \\\cline{2-7}
    & 3.3 & Assemblierung & PL & 28.02.19 & Funktionstest & PL \\\hline
%
 \multirow{2}{=}{Software}
    & 4.1 & Node & PL & 05.03.19 & Funktionstest & PL \\\cline{2-7}
    & 4.2 & Host & PL & 10.03.19 & Funktionstest & PL \\
    \hline
%
\multirow{3}{*}{Tests}
     & 5.1 & Node Tests & PL & 12.01.19 & Schriftlicher Review & PL \\ \cline{2-7}
    & 5.2 & Host Tests & PL & 16.01.19 & Schriftlicher Review & PL \\ \cline{2-7}
    & 5.3 & Systemtests & PL & 28.02.19 & Schriftlicher Review & PL \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

or with `tabularx` table environment and removing all `\cline` commands in table:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{longtable,
            makecell,   % <--new
            multirow,
            tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}

\usepackage[
  svgnames,
  table,
  ]{xcolor}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
\caption{Prüfplan}
\label{tab:pruefplan}
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\settowidth\rotheadsize{AP-Verantwortlich}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{| X % Phase
                  |c % PSP-Code
                  |>{\raggedright}p{0.21\linewidth} % AP
                  |l % AP-V.
                  |l % Datum
                  |l % Prüfmeth.
                  |l % Prüfer
                 |} 
    \hline
\rothead{Phase}
        & \rothead{PSP-Code}            & \rothead{Arbeitspaket\\ (AP)}
        & \rothead{AP-Verantwortlich}   & \rothead{Datum\\ (bis)}
        & \rothead{Prüfmethode}         & \rothead{Prüfungs\\ Verantwortlich.} \\ \hline 
%
\multirow{3}{=}{Projekt\-pläne}
    & 1.1 & Dokumentation & PL & 20.11.18 & Mündlicher Review & FAM \\
    & 1.2 & Projekt-Umweltanalyse & PL & 25.11.18 & Walk Through & SE \\\hline
%
\multirow{5}{=}{Grob\-planung}
   & 2.1 & Evaluation Node & PL & 04.12.18 & Mündlicher Review & DB \\
    & 2.2 & Evaluation Host & PL & 08.12.18 & Mündlicher Review & DB \\
    & 2.3 & Gewichtung der Evaluation & PL & 08.01.19 & Mündlicher Review & DB \\\hline
%
\multirow{3}{=}{Material}
    & 3.1 & BOM & PL & 12.01.19 & Walk-Through & PL \\
    & 3.2 & Bestellung & PL & 16.01.19 & Walk-Through & PL \\
    & 3.3 & Assemblierung & PL & 28.02.19 & Funktionstest & PL \\\hline
%
 \multirow{2}{=}{Software}
    & 4.1 & Node & PL & 05.03.19 & Funktionstest & PL \\
    & 4.2 & Host & PL & 10.03.19 & Funktionstest & PL \\
    \hline
%
\multirow{3}{*}{Tests}
    & 5.1 & Node Tests & PL & 12.01.19 & Schriftlicher Review & PL \\
    & 5.2 & Host Tests & PL & 16.01.19 & Schriftlicher Review & PL \\ 
    & 5.3 & Systemtests & PL & 28.02.19 & Schriftlicher Review & PL \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No need for `\multirow` if it belongs to odd lines:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage[svgnames,table,]{xcolor}
\newcommand\up[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\rotatebox{90}{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\noindent
{\tabcolsep=4pt
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{|>{\columncolor{LightSlateGray!10!white}}
            l % Phase
            |c % PSP-Code
            |X % AP
            |c % AP-V.
            |c % Datum
            |l % Prüfmeth.
            |c % Prüfer
            |} 
  \caption{Prüfplan}\label{tab:pruefplan}\\
  \rowcolor{LightSlateGray!10!white}
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{Phase} &   \up{PSP-Code} & \up{Arbeitspaket (AP)} & \up{AP-Verantwortlich} &
     \up{Datum (bis)} &     \multicolumn{1}{l}{Prüfmethode} & \up{Prüfungs Verantwortlich.}\\ \hline 
\endfirsthead
    \rowcolor{LightSlateGray!10!white}
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{Phase} & \up{PSP-Code} & \up{Arbeitspaket (AP)} & \up{AP-Verantwortlich} &
        \up{Datum (bis)} &  \multicolumn{1}{l}{Prüfmethode} & \up{Prüfungs Verantwortlich.}\\ \hline 
\endhead
 &1.1 & Dokumentation          & PL & 20.11.18 & Mündlicher Review    & FAM \\\cline{2-7} 
\multirow{-2}{*}{Projektpläne}  
 & 1.2 & Projekt-Umweltanalyse & PL & 25.11.18 & Walk Through         & SE \\\hline
 & 2.1 & Evaluation Node       & PL & 04.12.18 & Mündlicher Review    & DB \\\cline{2-7} 
 Grobplanung 
 & 2.2 & Evaluation Host       & PL & 08.12.18 & Mündlicher Review    & DB \\\cline{2-7} 
 & 2.3 & Gewichtung der Evaluation&PL& 08.01.19& Mündlicher Review    & DB \\\hline
 & 3.1 & BOM                   & PL & 12.01.19 & Walk-Through         & PL \\\cline{2-7} 
 Material   
 & 3.2 & Bestellung            & PL & 16.01.19 & Walk-Through         & PL \\\cline{2-7} 
 & 3.3 & Assemblierung         & PL & 28.02.19 & Funktionstest        & PL \\\hline
 & 4.1 & Node                  & PL & 05.03.19 & Funktionstest        & PL \\\cline{2-7} 
\multirow{-2}{*}{Software} 
 & 4.2 & Host                  & PL & 10.03.19 & Funktionstest        & PL \\\hline
 & 5.1 & Node Tests            & PL & 12.01.19 & Schriftlicher Review & PL \\\cline{2-7} 
 Tests  
 & 5.2 & Host Tests            & PL & 16.01.19 & Schriftlicher Review & PL \\\cline{2-7} 
 & 5.3 & Systemtests           & PL & 28.02.19 & Schriftlicher Review & PL \\\hline
\end{xltabular}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

While I don't know exactly why part of the word is covered, I can see that your particular issue is resolved by changing the `multirow{2}{*}[..]` commands to `multirow{1}{*}[..]`.

Here is the full working code which appears to fix your issue.

```
\documentclass[
10pt,
a4paper,
]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[
  svgnames,
  table,
  ]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\up}[2]{\rotatebox[origin=#1]{90}{#2}}
\begin{longtable}{|>{\columncolor{LightSlateGray!10!white}}
                   c % Phase
                  |p{0.02\paperwidth} % PSP-Code
                  |p{0.15\paperwidth} % AP
                  |p{0.03\paperwidth} % AP-V.
                  |p{0.05\paperwidth} % Datum
                  |p{0.18\paperwidth} % Prüfmeth.
                  |p{0.03\paperwidth} % Prüfer
                 |} \rowcolor{LightSlateGray!10!white}
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{Phase} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{\up{l}{PSP-Code}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{\up{l}{Arbeitspaket (AP)}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{\up{l}{AP-Verantwortlich}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{\up{l}{Datum (bis)}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{Prüfmethode} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{\up{l}{Prüfungs Verantwortlich.}}\\ \hline \endhead
  \multirow{1}{*}{Projektpläne} &
    1.1 & Dokumentation & PL & 20.11.18 &
    Mündlicher Review & FAM \\\cline{2-7} &
    1.2 & Projekt-Umweltanalyse & PL & 25.11.18 &
    Walk Through & SE \\\hline
  \multirow{3}{*}{Grobplanung} &
    2.1 & Evaluation Node & PL & 04.12.18 &
    Mündlicher Review & DB \\\cline{2-7} &
    2.2 & Evaluation Host & PL & 08.12.18 &
    Mündlicher Review  & DB \\\cline{2-7} &
    2.3 & Gewichtung der Evaluation & PL & 08.01.19 &
    Mündlicher Review & DB \\\hline
  \multirow{3}{*}{Material} &
    3.1 & BOM & PL & 12.01.19 &
    Walk-Through & PL \\\cline{2-7} &
    3.2 & Bestellung & PL & 16.01.19 &
    Walk-Through & PL \\\cline{2-7} &
    3.3 & Assemblierung & PL & 28.02.19 &
    Funktionstest & PL \\\hline
  \multirow{1}{*}{Software} &
    4.1 & Node & PL & 05.03.19 &
    Funktionstest & PL \\\cline{2-7} &
    4.2 & Host & PL & 10.03.19 &
    Funktionstest & PL \\\cline{2-7}
  \multirow{3}{*}{Tests} &
    5.1 & Node Tests & PL & 12.01.19 &
    Schriftlicher Review & PL \\\cline{2-7} &
    5.2 & Host Tests & PL & 16.01.19 &
    Schriftlicher Review & PL \\\cline{2-7} &
    5.3 & Systemtests & PL & 28.02.19 &
    Schriftlicher Review & PL \\\hline
  \caption{Prüfplan}
  \label{tab:pruefplan}
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```